# Grails.pass parameters from the controller to external .js file?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have controller:

```
package plugin

class TestController {

def simply = {[name:new Date()]}
}
```

as you see i pass param `name`

my view page:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'resource/js',file:'simply.js')}?color=FA8DFF">-->

<g:javascript>
    alert("${name}")
</g:javascript>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

this page run correct - afrer load i see alert window with current date :)

but, when

view page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'resource/js',file:'simply.js')}?color=FA8DF">
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and external simply.js file:

```
alert("${name}")
```

i see empty alert window. So, my question: how i can pass params to external.js file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two stages in parsing the view when it is displayed to the user. State one is the server executing any code contained in the view page. In your case

```
${name}
```

Is turned into the current date since that’s the value from the controller. This means that the text sent to the users browser contains 3/2/2010 instead of ${name}

The second stage that takes place when the user accesses a view is the browser parsing the HTML. The HTML that is sent to the browser depends on what took place on the server. Since in your example the JavaScript is contained in the view ${name} is replaced with the current date on the server. Then JavaScript containing 3/3/2010 is sent to the browser since ${name} was replaced by 3/3/2010 on the server. This means the popup box will contain 3/3/2010. If you include external JavaScript files they never get run through the first step since the browser directly downloads them and does not make a request to the server. This means that the first step never takes place so $[name} does not get replaced with the value from your controller. This behavior is the same weather you use the

```
<script>
```

or

```
<g:javascript>
```

tag.
In order to pass values from a view into JavaScript located in an external file you should define your JavaScript as functions in external files if you wish to pass parameters. For example in external.js

```
Function dispDate(theParam)
{
Alert(theParam);
}
```

Then from your view

```
<g:javascript src="external.js" />
<script type="text/JavaScript">
dispDate(“${name}”);
 </script>
```

Where external.js is stored in the web-app/js directory.

Comment: wow, a wonderful way!  but that would be the Grails itself render the external file